# Which is static and which is singleton in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Type 1:

```
class TestExample {
      object Bell {
       fun  add(){

       }
   }

 Class B{
  TestExample.Bell.add()
}
```

Type 2:

```
class TestExample {
      companion object Bell {
       fun  add(){

       }
   }



Class B{
TestExample.add()
 }
```

In this type 1 and type 2, which is static example and which is singleton example? Both behaves similar behavior right?

Comment: probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814616/kotlin-difference-between-object-and-companion-object-in-a-class

Comment: Also, learn how to read the bytecode, and therefore observe the differences between each: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35538539/2684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html):

> **Object declarations**
>
> If you need a singleton - a class that only has got one instance - you
>   can declare the class in the usual way, but use the object keyword
>   instead of class
>
> **Companion objects**
>
> If you need a function or a property to be tied to a class rather than
>   to instances of it (similar to @staticmethod in Python), you can
>   declare it inside a companion object